# How can I featurise / store changes to a view provided by a module?

Tags: 7, features

In my case, Workbench and Workbench Moderation. Workbench Moderation gives me a "My Drafts" and "Needs review" view which I can edit to my taste, but I can't see a way of featurising the view or preserving my modifications in some way.

Is there an approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmaticaly alter the view with the following steps:

1. Make changes to the view lik you would do to any view.
2. Export the view and save the code returned.
3. Create a module and add the [hook_views_default_views_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views_alter/7) function (together with the [hook_views_api()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7) function.
4. Check the $views array for your view machine name and set `$views['your_view'] = PASTED VIEWS EXPORT`.

Now you may revert your view and the changes you made will be kept as the default settings.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot featurize a view that is provided by a module. What you can do is clone the view and featurize that.

I don't know about the Workbench modules specifically, but some modules allow you to choose which view is displayed via the UI. If they don't allow that, you will likely need to go in and modify the view call manually in a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a guide here which supplements lukedekker's answer with regard to overriding default views:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1014774